# Tag <b> is ignored in mobile?

Tags: html, mobile, tags, cross-browser, semantics

I got an information, from a senior developer, that the tag `<b>` is ignored in mobile browsers, but I could not find this information anywhere on internet.

According to him, all mobile browsers uses the tag `<b>` on the entire page, so styling this tag take makes no sense, as it would style all page.

Is this true? Is there a reference on internet to confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 0):

He is **wrong**. Unless you wrap your whole page in a `<b>` tag it wouldn't style everything.
Here's reference about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```html
<b>
```

tag works in mobile browser.I tried the emulator.
http://mobiletest.me/-This site helps us to test different mobile browsers.Try to change the HTML content using 'inspect element' feature in the browser.